# Get JSON format from adwords api report

Tags: python, json, api, google-ads-api

So I'm building an application which has a frontend in React and a backend
in python (pyramid framework).
I recently integrated the google adwords api to query custom reports (doing this in python).
I'm able to get a report from the api by making a query.
However, the response comes either in xml or csv format. The api doesn't support json response at the moment.

My question is: how can I get the data to json format and send it back to my frontend so I can display it in my webapp?

Comment: any success in getting data in json?